# "How to set Cache-Control headers in Liferay for custom API?"

Tags: http-headers, liferay-6, cache-control

I have written a custom API in Liferay which in cache enabled and working fine on logs(when I hit it the first time it fetches data from database and second time it fetches from webCachePool) but, when I am checking it from browser's network it is not showing any information of cache header (cache-control: private, no-cache, , no-store, must-revalidate)

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, Liferay 6.2 CE.

I expect the cache-control header like this:
Cache-Control:private, max-age:86400

Answer (score 0):

Liferay sets "Cache-Control" headers in [HeaderFilter.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/servlet/filters/header/HeaderFilter.java), that filter can be configured in [[TOMCAT]/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml) file.

You can modify default "Cache-Control" values or add new ones changing **liferay-web.xml** values.

**(update)**

In Liferay Portal 6.2, that configuration only applies to Liferay out-of-the-box functionalities.

If you want to apply it to your own developed Liferay applications, you have also to edit file **[tomcat]/webapps/[your-app]/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml**, that file is added by Liferay during application deployment and it is a copy of **[speed-filters-web.xml](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/dependencies/speed-filters-web.xml)** that it is inside portal-impl.jar, folder com/liferay/portal/deploy/dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added 
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>Header Filter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/documents/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
these lines in liferay-web.xml. When i am getting data of document then it is showing "Cache-Control:max-age=315360000, public". But when i am getting data from any outher service then still it is showing Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store. How to set values in liferay-web.xml for web services to get respose like this "Cache-Control:max-age=315360000, public".

Comment: Hi @Seema

I have updated my original comment, you have also to modify [tomcat]/webapps/[your-app]/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml in your own application, for more information see updated comment above

Comment: Hi jorgediaz-lr I have added properties of "speed-filters-web.xml" in [tomcat]/webapps/[my-app]/WEB-INF/web.xml. I also added <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>Header Filter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>*/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> in web.xml. But still i am getting cache information like Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store

Comment: Hi @Seema

Don't modify "web.xml" file, you have to modify "liferay-web.xml" file that it is created in [tomcat]/webapps/[your-app]/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml after deploying your application in deploy folder of Liferay

If you want to automate that change, it is also possible to modify com/liferay/portal/deploy/dependencies/speed-filters-web.xml file inside portal-impl.jar.

Please, read again my last comment, because I didn't say to modify "web.xml" file.

Comment: Hi @jorgediaz-lr I have added properties of "speed-filters-web.xml" in **[tomcat]/webapps/[your-app]/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml**, and removed from **[tomcat]/webapps/[my-app]/WEB-INF/web.xml**. I have restart the portal and checked again. But it is showing Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store cache information.